# C# - DateTime Constructor Call

Tags: c#, datetime

So, I have this program that has a constructor with the inputs as DateTime.

But whenever I try to create the object of that Class, and pass the DateTime as argument, there is an error.

The code is as follows:

```
 public Student(DateTime dob)
        {
            DateofBirth = dob;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myprogram = new Student(1995,04,29);
```

But, it's showing error in the Student class stating that constructor cannot take three arguments. Please help!

PS: There is code above and below, so ignore the brackets.

Comment: Your Student constructor only accepts 1 argument which is of type `DateTime`, you might want to format the inputs in your `Program` class to create a `DateTime` object and use it in the constructor

Comment: The error is correct, `DateTime dob` != `1995, 04, 29` you may be missing a `DateTime` variable declaration to use as the constructor argument (Henningsson's answer), or maybe another constructor with year, month and day parameters (Jon Skeet's answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well yes - you're trying to pass three integer arguments to the constructor, but it accepts a `DateTime` value. You're not currently creating a `DateTime` value. All you need to do is change your constructor call to:

```
var myprogram = new Student(new DateTime(1995, 4, 29));
```

This will *not* happen implicitly - you need to tell the compiler that you really *did* mean to create a `DateTime`.

As an alternative you *could* add a `Student` constructor to create the `DateTime` and chain to the other constructor:

```
public Student(int year, int month, int day)
    : this(new DateTime(year, month, day))
```

but that doesn't seem like a good idea to me for a `Student` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your class takes a DateTime as a argument, not three integers. Try this:

```
var myprogram = new Student(new DateTime(1995,04,29));
```